# wait for parse.com delete to finish before rendering screen

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My code below will delete my row but it will display the error message.
Any ideas?

```
delete: function(id) {
            // Check login
            if (!Parse.User.current()) {
                this.navigate('#/login', { trigger: true });
            } else {
                var query = new Parse.Query(Blog);
                query.get(id, {
                    success: function(id) {
                        id.destroy({});
                            alert('Delete Successful');

                        },
                        error: function(blog, error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            alert('Error in delete query');
                        }
                    });
            }

        }
    });
```

My script for parse is..

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Morgan. To help potential answerers, Please add further information. Like what error you are getting? What is the code of the error? Why does it get into the error block even though you say it is deleting successfully after entering the success block. What do you mean by wait for parse.com and then render screen (I suppose you mean Async response block)? Why is your question different than its title? cheers

Comment: Been working it for days and not sure what the error was before  except i have not been able to refresh data after success and show the deleted item gone. when i attempt to delete it again i have a message that it is not there and then refresh shows it gone. please explain Async response block.

Comment: I am not qualified to answer `javascript` questions but Async response block is the success and error block inside your `query.get` method. You can perform success actions (e.g. rendering a new screen) in your `success : function(id){}` condition block.

Comment: i got it going thanks for the help.